# Flyback transformer for fusor?

Tags: voltage, fusion

I've always wanted to construct a [farnsworth nuclear fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor). I recently ordered a 3-6 volt to 400,000 volt flyback transformer, and was wondering if that could be used in a fusor setup

Comment: I'm interested in the answers you get, but if you got one of these you're likely to be disappointed (I got some for the same reason and they're more like 40kV): http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1311.R1.TR3.TRC0.A0.H0.X400kv.TRS0&_nkw=400kv&_sacat=0

Comment: Ah, i see. Well, i have low expectations, considering it was 8 USD. Even so, I would think it would still be enough to fuse hydrogen

Comment: No. It won't work.

Comment: Can a Tesla coil be used to create a fusor?

Comment: I suspect NOT. The wiki article suggests a particle accelerator is needed. They mention that the back ends of CRT's (older TV tubes) have been used.

Comment: To accelerate particles you need a vacuum,  an oscillator and a magnetic field to contain the beam

Comment: Well yes, I was just assuming that the charged grids of the fusor would provide sufficient focusing